# How can I find and delete MongoDb Collection Entity's in one move and save system resources

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have a mongodb collection with realtime data with a short lifecycle.
When I need them I also want to delete the once I find,

Here's pseudo code using morphia wrapper:

```
for(LogEntity log: mongo.find(LogEntity.class, "grabMe", true)){
    mongo.delete(mongo.createQuery(LogEntity.class).filter("logId", log.id));
    //Do work and dispose the log
}
```

I'm running some tests on this and its really difficult to simulate a heavy load because this is part of Google GCM.

This is running in a `Runnable` that are fed from an `ScheduledExecutorService` `scheduleAtFixedRate` every 2 sec.

Is this going to work or is there a better way to do this. How is the `find()` working in this situation. Will I mess up the find()'s internal array by deleting from it. If there are many `LogEntity` I cannot hold them in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heavy load logging with short lifecycle, I will choose capped collection. in this situation, you cannot delete a document in the capped collection.

on the other hand, if you wanna choose normal collection for logging and do a timed clean up, your find and delete loop is slow. if your code is `foreach item in collection.find(query) {collection.remove({_id:item._id};}` use `collection.remove(query)` method instead.

Comment: Will test the the capped collection. Where do you find `remove` in the `Datastore`. `collection.remove(query)`

Comment: which programming language do you use? `collection.remote(query)` is in mongodb shell, generally javascript. based on your code, i quess it  might be `mongo.delete(mongo.createQuery(LogEntity.class).filter("grabMe", true));`